# How can I print an element from a list one by one starting by first element and increment until the last one in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to select a specific element in a column:

```
Clu1 = df1.loc[df1['Cluster1'] == n]
Clu2 = df2.loc[df2['Cluster2'] == n]
```

the number 'n' need to be selected from a range ex [0, 1, 2, 3] I need to run my simulation and for the first run 'n' should be equal to '0', second run 'n' = 1, third run 'n' = 2, and last 'n' = 3

as solutions that I tried:

```
values = list(range(0, best_size))
for n in values:
    print(n)
output:
0
1
2
3
```

The ouptut is a list and I need only one by one

second:

```
values = list(range(0, best_size))
n = random.choice(values)
n
```

the output is random which is not practical in my case

Any Suggestion ? I use Jupyter, python 3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Python 3.x `range` returns a generator, you don't need to turn that into a list. Just

```py
for n in range(stop_value):
     print(n)
```

is sufficient.

Comment: I try it, but it gives me a list. I need only one for each run of my code. for example when I use random.choice() it gives me one element but randomly.  This n value will help me to use loc into the column that have rows 0, and then rows equal 1 and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you need. `range` does return a `range` which behaves like a generator. `random.choice(range(low, high))` would return you random integer in the (closed) range [low, high-1]. `random.choices(seq, k=count)` would get you `count` random items from `seq`

Comment: Thank you, EdvardM. Yes I tried this also sorted(random.choices(mylist, k=1))  it gives me the number but they are not ordered and there is no stop value because I need that command stop when it select all values from the list. I tried this also i += 1 it gives me a sequnence of number and this is what I want but it start from 1 and there is no stop value too, so initiate i = 0 but when I use it again it gives me the same value 0. What I need is a unique number start from 0 and increment (each time the program is run) until the stoping value.

Comment: could you do just `random.shuffle(lst)` and then say `sorted(lst[:count])` given how many you want?

Comment: Yes I try it by setting the count to 1 to get one element but still random, now i try to use the while loop as follow: best_size = 4
 i =0

 while i <best_size:
       G = print('GP =', pd.concat([df1.loc[df1['Cluster'] == i], df2.loc[df2['Cluster'] == i]],  sort=True))             i = i +1  now i need just to save it in multiple excel file and this what I ask here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339061/save-a-loop-output-into-different-excel-file-in-python